# Contacting individual Page fans directly?

Tags: facebook-wall, facebook-page

I was wondering what options are available for directly contacting specific fans of a Page.

What I've found so far is that it is possible for a Page admin to send a private message, using the Send Dialog, but that the message will appear to come from the admin rather than the Page itself.

It seems that Wall Posts won't work at all unless the admin is actually friends with the fan.

I have been unable to dig up any info on whether sending Invites/Requests would work from a Page to a fan.

Can anyone provide a more complete view of what's possible with the current APIs with regards to Pages contacting individual fans directly? It would be much appreciated and I'm sure useful to other developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API method to even get a list of fans of a page and so there definitely isn't a way to contact fans of page via the API.  Once migrating your page to Timeline, fan pages can now receive private messages from fans and can reply to fans via the website, but there is currently no API methods for doing so. Also, fan pages cannot send a private message to a fan unless a fan first messages them.

Comment: I could, however, get the IDs of fans who have liked/commented on the Page's posts, correct? These are the users I'd want to contact directly anyway.

Comment: On the matter of sending requests, we are able to send requests from an app to users which have not authorized the app, otherwise they would be rather useless. They don't have very high visibility though, of course. But I'm wondering if it's possible for a Page to send a request (acting as a regular user of the app) as opposed to an admin of that Page.

Comment: Now that Pages are able to send private messages, is it possible to do so through the Send Dialog?

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the timeline change.  There is still no API method for contacting users.  The send dialog will still only allow you to send requests to people a user is friends with.